# Marketing Cloud - Access all in-app messages (modal) in a device

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

A) I sent 5 in-app messages using Journey Builder and I would like to have access to all of their objects **at once**. Is there a way to do that? Currently, I'm using `setInAppMessageListener` which is only shows the latest in-app message when the user opens the app.

B) Also, is there a way to manually delete a downloaded in-app message via the SDK? I want to 'skip' a certain message in the user device and show the next one in line.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK will only present 1 message at a time, however, you could call `showMessage(id: String)` to show the messages back-to-back.

There is no way to manually delete a message from the device, however, you can use the SDK's `shouldShowMessage(message: Message)` interface to apply your own business logic. Returning `false` would effectively swallow the message.

Comment: Returning `false` in `shouldShowMessage` ignores the message in the current session, but if the user reopens the app that same message appears in `shouldShowMessage` again. It seems like the only way to get 'rid' of a message is by showing it, is this correct?

Comment: It can be deleted on the server and will be removed from the device. Aside from that, there is no way to manually delete a message from the device.

Comment: That's an interesting use case. You should open a "Voice of Customer" request through your account representative.